# search and open files in Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In some base directory, which contains many sub folders and files, I have to search for a PDF file, and if the required file is found, I have to open it using Command Prompt. This is what I have been trying to do, the code I used to extract the address of the file is as follows, the code is incomplete, please help me complete it. (I made this as a .bat file and run it.) 
how to open the file at the address which is being saved in the text file?

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set /p bn=Enter the Bridge NO:
Z: 
cd "Z:\OHE_Design\DFCC\EMP-4 OHE\Submissions\References\Received\CTP-1 & 2\05-Bridge Mast files\CTP 1 & 2 DETAILS\OHE approval letters" 
dir /s *%bn%.pdf > "C:\Users\suneelp\Desktop\temp.txt" 
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`more +3 C:\Users\suneelp\Desktop\temp.txt`) DO (     
    echo %%a>C:\Users\suneelp\Desktop\temp.txt   
    goto :leave
) 
:leave 
pause
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: how to convert the address which is in notepad, to a string value of a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just retrieve the whole path together with the filename, and "start" it - Windows will use the default handler for this extension:

```
@echo off
set spath="Z:\OHE_Design\DFCC\EMP-4 OHE\Submissions\References\Received\CTP-1 & 2\05-Bridge Mast files\CTP 1 & 2 DETAILS\OHE approval letters"
set /p bn=Enter the Bridge NO:
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b %spath%\*%bn%.pdf') do @cmd /c "%%f"
```

So, no `cd` to the searched path/volume necessary, nor the `delayedexpansion` or `pause`. The command will only end if the document is closed.

Comment: This programme doesnot search for the file, it directly assumes the path that we have mentioned.

Comment: Well it does. The file(s) are searched via `dir /s` in and below the given path. Note the wildcard.